# Error al redimensionar componentes Swing en Java

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio en Java Swing, que debe de funcionar así:

Dentro del `JFrame`, hay un objeto `JSplitPane` que tiene un `JList` dentro de un `JSrollPane` y un `JPanel`. El primer objeto debe de modificar sus tamaños mínimo, máximo y preferido por sus métodos `setMinimumSize()`, `setMaximumSize()` y `setPreferredSize()`, los cuales toman como referencia el ancho del frame para dimensionarse. Estos tres métodos están dentro del método `componentResized()` del objeto escucha `ComponentAdapter`.

Al iniciar la aplicación, no me respeta las reglas que coloqué en los argumentos de los métodos, y cuando se redimensiona, tampoco toma como referencia el ancho del frame.

Éste es el código. Ojalá lo prueben redimensionando el frame y el componente para que se den cuenta de mi problema y puedan ayudarme.

```java
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class ComVisor extends JFrame
{
private JList imagesList;
private JPanel imagePanel;
private JSplitPane mainPanel;
private JScrollPane scrollPanelRight;
private int width;

public ComVisor(String nameApplication)
{
    setFrame(nameApplication);
    setComponents();
}

private void setFrame(String nameApplication)
{
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(1, 3));
    setTitle(nameApplication);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(new Dimension(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    this.addWindowListener(
        new WindowAdapter() 
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
            { 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ComVisor.this, nameApplication + "-Salida");
            }
        }
    );
    this.addComponentListener(
        new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent E)
            {   
                width = getWidth();

                scrollPanelRight.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width / 3, 0));
                scrollPanelRight.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width / 7, 0));
                scrollPanelRight.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width / 5 * 4, 0));zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz  
            }
        }
    );  
}

private void setComponents()
{
    String[] a = {"dsdsdsd", "dsdsdkkhskj", "dskhkjdhskjdhksdh", "sdskdhskjhds"};
    JButton b = new JButton("Soy un boton xD");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    imagesList = new JList(a);
    p.add(b);
    imagesList.setVisibleRowCount(100);
    scrollPanelRight = new JScrollPane(imagesList);
    mainPanel = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, scrollPanelRight, p);
    add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

private class Manejador implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent listener)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Y esta es la clase principal:

```java
import static javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater;

public class Principal
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    invokeLater( 
        new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new ComVisor("ComVisor").setVisible(true);s
            }
        }
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de cambiar las dimensiones manualmente, deberías usar los Layout, y ajustar las preferencias de relación de tamaño en ese lugar. En mis proyectos nunca tuve problemas configurando bien los Layout de los jFrame/JPanel.